# rank and nullity of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the vector space of all continuous functions over $[0,1]$ and let $T:V\to V$ be defined by $T(f(x))=\int\limits_0^1f(t)\sin (x-t)dt$ for all $f\in V$ and for all $x\in [0,1]$. Clearly $T$ is a linear transformation. I want to find to kernel and range of $T$. Here I got stuck. How to show that ker$T$ is trivial or nontrivial? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have for $x,t \in \mathbb R$
$$\sin(x-t) = \sin x \cos t -\cos x \sin t$$ therefore
$$T(f(x))=\sin x \int\limits_0^1f(t)\cos t \ dt - \cos x \int\limits_0^1f(t)\sin t \  dt$$ Hence a continuous $f$ is part of the kernel if and only if
$$\int\limits_0^1f(t)\cos t \ dt = \int\limits_0^1f(t)\sin t \  dt = 0$$

Then you'll be able to prove that the range of $T$ are the functions $x \mapsto a \sin x + b \cos x$ where $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: why cant the kernel be $x: x=\arctan(\frac{\int_0^1 f(t)\sin t dt}{\int_0^1 f(t)\cos t dt})?$

Comment: @vidyarthi $x:\tan x=\frac{\int_0^1 f(t)\sin t dt}{\int_0^1 f(t)\cos t dt}$ is not a function of $x$.